# Мой код с использованием progress модуля не работает!

Tags: python, progress-bar

Следуя инструкции установил первым делом модуль через pip install, дальше взял код из примера, и он не работает!

```
from progress.bar import Bar

bar = Bar('Processing', max=20)
for i in range(20):
    # Do some work
    bar.next()
bar.finish()
```

Попробовал использовать другой пример, с загрузкой спиннером, но тоже не сработало.
Благодарю всех заранее за уделённое моему вопросу время!

Comment: Если запускаете через PyCharm, то нужно включить в нем эмуляцию терминала

Answer (score -1):

Используйте лучше широко известный модуль `tqdm`, он работает практически везде и пользоваться им очень просто:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(20), desc='Processing'):
    # Do some work
    pass
```